# What is meaning of PT and S in values returned from Microsoft get call records api?

Tags: call, microsoft-teams, call-recording, microsoft-graph-api

Microsoft call records api - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/callrecords-callrecord-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http returns field values with prefix PT and suffix S.
Does it mean point and Seconds ?

eg.  "averageRoundTripTime": "PT0.005S" or   "maxJitter": "PT0.02S" , what PT and S denotes ?

Comment: Please refer this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168022/what-does-pt-prefix-stand-for-in-duration

Comment: @Neema Bisht- Did you get chance to check the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168022/what-does-pt-prefix-stand-for-in-duration

Comment: @Sayali-MSFT , Chetan attached thread in comment answers my question. This question can be closed. Thank you