# Parse media presentation time from dash manifest java?

Tags: java, time, simpledateformat

In a streaming video dash manifest we receive the period start time as `PT461486H44M42.24S`. This is basically a timestamp for the media segment to be loaded.
Sample will be

```
  <Period id="C 2022-08-26 08-45-41" start="PT461486H44M42.24S">
```

I want to know what is this time format? And how can I convert it to long milliseconds.
I checked the `[SimpleDateFormat]` [SDF](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) but it doesn't matches.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does 'PT' prefix stand for in Duration?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51168022/what-does-pt-prefix-stand-for-in-duration)

Comment: `PT461486H44M42.24S` is how long the presentation takes, its duration. `SimpleDateFormat` cannot handle durations, you are right. Which is somehow good because the `SimpleDateFormat` class is also notoriously troublesome and long outdated, nothing that you should want to struggle with under any circumstances at all. As the answer already says use `Duration` from [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API,](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: I don’t know Dash, but suspect there may be something wrong with your data. [One example I found here](https://ottverse.com/single-period-vs-multi-period-dash/) has `<Period start="PT32S" id="2">`, so `start` is 32 seconds, not 52 years like yours. I can’t understand how both can make sense. [This page](https://dashif-documents.azurewebsites.net/Guidelines-TimingModel/master/Guidelines-TimingModel.html) has example that are 20 seconds and 300 seconds (5 minutes).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `String` seems to represent a duration in ISO-8601 format.

You can use [`java.time.Duration.parse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) in order to create a `Duration` which may give you information about specific unit. Since a duration is an amount of time in contrast to epoch millis, you should not convert `Duration.toMillis()` to any date or datetime. They are basically totally different.

Here's an example usage of a `Duration` derived from your `String`:

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // your example String
    String durStr = "PT461486H44M42.24S";
    // parse it to a Duration
    Duration duration = Duration.parse(durStr);
    // create a result message from the units of a Duration
    String durMsg = String.format("%d milliseconds are %d days, %d hours, %d minutes, %d seconds and %d milliseconds",
                                duration.toMillis(),
                                duration.toDays(),
                                duration.toHoursPart(), 
                                duration.toMinutesPart(), 
                                duration.toSecondsPart(), 
                                duration.toMillisPart());
    // print the result message
    System.out.println(durMsg);
}
```

Output:

```
1661352282240 milliseconds are 19228 days, 14 hours, 44 minutes, 42 seconds and 240 milliseconds
```

---

If you suspect the result of `duration.toMillis()` not to be the length of the video but , for example, the creation timestamp (in epoch millis) or the age in millis, don't use the outdated API (`Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and so on) but use `java.time`. You can use those millis to create an `Instant` which you can then use to create a `ZonedDateTime` of `OffsetDateTime`:

```java
// create a Temporal using an Instant and a fixed offset (UTC / +00:00 here)
OffsetDateTime odt = Instant.EPOCH.plus(duration)
                                  .atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
// print the result
System.out.println(odt);
```

Output:

```
2022-08-24T14:44:42.240Z
```

---

Different idea:

You can subtract the parsed `Duration` from a current moment in time, which – under circumstances – may give you the *moment in* time of the first media presentation (like when it was released):

```java
Instant instant = Instant.now().minus(duration);
OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
System.out.println(odt);
```

This just output the following:

```
1970-01-01T21:37:52.460090Z
```

This approach is just an idea and it heavily depends on the duration between receiving the media presentation time (your `String`) and the calculation involving `Instant.now()`, which should ideally be the same moment in time in order to get the (most) correct time of the media presentation.

Comment: You're welcome… Pay attention when calculating with millis represented as a duration ;-)

Comment: Hi @deHaar, can I know the JDK version that you are using? I'm getting compilation errors for `toHoursPart()`, `toMinutesPart()`, `toSecondsPart()`, and `toMillisPart()`.

Comment: I used Java 11, and those methods were introduced in Java 9, I think.

Comment: Good answer and a good edit. A minor detail and a matter of taste. For my part I like the fluent writing style that java.time often lends itself well to. So I’d do `OffsetDateTime odt = Instant.EPOCH.plus(duration).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);`. The result is still `2022-08-24T14:44:42.240Z`, the same as you got. And in the last example simply `OffsetDateTime odt = instant.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);`.

Comment: @deHaar thanks for the answer. I also want the millis to convert it back to same format `PT461486H44M42.24S`. I explored the `Instant` but it doesn't give the same output. Anything to help on this?

Comment: @WISHY That's really easy: It's the `Duration.toString()` method which produces such a `String` value. If you have millis, create a `Duration.ofMillis()` (or take any `Duration`) and use it's `toString()`.